# Can't send patch request to Lotus Domino server

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, restsharp, lotus

I'm trying to use REST Api at Domino server as described here: [Document patch](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html#ddapi_ref_document_patch)

When I send request through [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) everything works fine, but when I try to make same request programatically through [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) it through out error 415 `Unsupported Media Type`.

- This is my **vb.net** code which I use to send request:

  ```
  Function Execute(request As RestRequest) As RestResponse
          Dim client As New RestClient(baseUrl)
          request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
          request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")

  Dim response = client.Execute(request)

  If response.StatusCode <> 200 Then
      Throw New ApplicationException(response.StatusDescription)
  End If

  If response.ErrorException IsNot Nothing Then
      Throw New ApplicationException("Error retrieving response.  Check inner details for more info.", response.ErrorException)
  End If

    Return response
  End Function

  Public Sub SetState(DocUNID As String, state As String)
   Dim request = New RestRequest()
   request.Method = Method.PATCH
   request.Resource = "api/data/documents/unid/{DocUNID}"
   request.AddParameter("EMPCARDSTATE", state)
   Execute(request)
  End Sub
  ```
- This is my **Postman** screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled the PATCH method for the server?  I believe it may be disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

The data service returns 415 when you send a PATCH request and the Content-Type header value is *not* application/json.  I am not familiar with vb.net, but I can only conclude this statement is not working as expected:

```
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
```

This statement also looks wrong to me:

```
request.AddParameter("EMPCARDSTATE", state)
```

You want to write a JSON object to the body of the request.  I think you intend to include an "EMPCARDSTATE" property in the JSON object.  Does `request.AddParameter()` really set the body of the request?

I recommend changing your code to correctly set the body of the request.  That could be all you need to resolve the problem.  If you still see a 415 error, you can use Fiddler (or a similar tool) to check the request for both the Content-Type header and the body.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem was in RestShart itself, see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that the problem was with RestSharp implementation of POST/PATCH vs GET. When I was sending POST/PATCH with parameter template in url as following `...{PARAMETER}` it was throwing an exception. If I concatenate url before using it, everything works fine.

Comment: This answer could be improved by including the code changes that made it work.  Also, the original post said the REST API was returning 415.  This answer says RestSharp was throwing an exception.  That seems like a different problem to me.

Comment: You're right, I'll include code tomorrow. Regarding the answer I'll improve it tomorrow, actually it isn't my problem I just tried to help my colleague which hasn't SO account but he discovered answer himself. I just insisted not to delete answer because it might safe a lot of time for somebody else.